# MFA authentication using Python boto for DynamoDb

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, boto, multi-factor-authentication

I've a old code which looks like something below

```
boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region(
        region_name=AWS_REGION,
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

My organization has mandated MFA authentication recently. So this code gives me

```
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'Message': u'User: arn:aws:iam::123123123123:user/mike.ross is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123123123:table/MyTable with an explicit deny', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#AccessDeniedException'}
```

I tried to search Internet for code examples which use MFA authentication but so far I'm unsuccessful.

So far, I tried to add `session_token` parameter but it did not recognize the parameter. Then I tried removing all the parameters from the `connect_to_region` method and exported follwing environment variables with appropriate values

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

Then I got

```
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The security token included in the request is invalid.', u'__type': u'com.amazon.coral.service#UnrecognizedClientException'}
```

How do I change this code to use MFA authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Its explained pretty well here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_mfa_configure-api-require.html

1. Post your Device Serial Number and Token Code to the [GetSessionToken endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetSessionToken.html)
2. Receive Temporary Access Key ID and Secret Access Key from the GetSessionToken endpoint
3. Pass temporary tokens into your existing code

Comment: I know the process and how it works. What I am unable to find an example how to do that. Theoretically, your answer is correct. But what I'm asking is the way to do it. For example, the third step I know I've to pass the temporary tokens. But how to pass them is the question. I can't find a method which takes the input.

Comment: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.get_session_token

Answer (score 0):

I was making a silly mistake. I should've been exposing `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN` instead I was exposing it as `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`

I needed to expose following environment variables

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = <AWS access key if mfa one time access key>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = <AWS secret key if mfa one time secret key>
AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN = <if mfa security token>
AWS_PROFILE = <profile name from your /.aws/credentials file>
```

After exposing this environment variables I changed the code as below

```
boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region(region_name=AWS_REGION)
# Observe that I've removed access, secret key parameters, 
# instead they'll be taken from environment variables.
```

Now, the connection worked properly.

Reference: [Boto documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html)